# Как с помощью Js или jQ переключать css свойство?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать на `js или jq` скрипт, который переключает `css` свойство в зависимости от того какая страница открыта?

Вот на `php` как-то так бы это выглядело:

```
<?php if($_GET['profile']){ ?> тут добавлялось бы какое-то css свойство<?php } ?>
```

А как такое сделать на `Js`?

Comment: Если сайт сделан с помощью php то именно в этом случае правильнее использовать php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы могли бы попробовать сделать так:

```
var rootUrl= document.location.href;
if (rootUrl === "yoursite-domain.ru/profile") {
   var reverseEl = document.getElementById("prettify-lang");
   reverseEl.classList.add("yourClass");
}
```

Может не сработать если скрипт уже загрузился а html элемента с искомым id еще нет на странице, так что лучше добавить скрипт перед `</body>` или обернуть в onload()

Comment: А если jq то var reverseEl = $("#prettify-lang");
   reverseEl.addClass("yourClass");